First Chern number of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ normal bundle inside $\mathbb{CP}^2$
This question was briefly discussed in Calculating the Chern class of the normal bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$ inside of $\mathbb{CP^{n+1}}$, but the Chern number was not explicitly calculated. I tried to calculate this using two methods and they don't seem to agree. Here's what I did:
The tangent bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^2$, restricted to $\mathbb{CP}^1$, is a direct sum of the tangent and normal bundles of $\mathbb{CP}^1$. Using the Whitney sum formula, we deduce that $c_1(T\mathbb{CP}^2|_{\mathbb{CP}^1}) = c_1(T\mathbb{CP}^1) + c_1(N\mathbb{CP}^1)$. Denoting $c_1(T\mathbb{CP}^1)$ as $x \in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1)$, the LHS can be expressed as $2x$, since $c(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = (1+x)^2 = 1 + 2x + x^2$, where the last term is automatically zero when restricted to $\mathbb{CP}^1$. Thus, we have shown that $x = c_1(N \mathbb{CP}^1)$, i.e. $c_1(N \mathbb{CP}^1)=c_1(T \mathbb{CP}^1)$.
Using the Kaehler potential $K = $ log $(1+z_i \bar{z}^i)$, where $i=1,2,...,n$, the standard Fubini-Study metric for $\mathbb{CP}^n$ can be obtained by $g_{i\bar{j}} = \partial_i \partial_{\bar{j}}K$, and the Ricci form obeys $R=-i \partial \bar{\partial}$ log $\sqrt{|g|}$.
For $\mathbb{CP}^1$, we have $g_{z\bar{z}}=(1+z\bar{z})^{-2}$, giving $R = \frac{2i}{(1+z\bar{z})^{2}} dz \wedge d\bar{z}$. As the first Chern class is given as $c_1(T\mathbb{CP}^1)=$ tr$\frac{R}{2\pi}$, we let $z=r e^{i \theta}$ and it follows that the first Chern number is $\int_{\mathbb{CP}^1} c_1(T\mathbb{CP}^1) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int \frac{r dr d\theta}{(1+r^2)^2} = 2$ (which I'm sure is correct, since the integral over the top Chern class of the tangent bundle should agree with the Euler characteristic, which is 2 in this case as $\mathbb{CP}^1 \cong S^2$). Thus, using the previous argument, the first Chern number of the normal bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ inside $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is 2.
However, when I manually calculate the integral over $c_1(T \mathbb{CP}^2)$ using the Fubini-Study metric and taking one of the $z_i$ 's to zero (for the restriction to $\mathbb{CP}^1$), I get 6, implying that $\int_{\mathbb{CP}^1} c_1(N\mathbb{CP}^1) = 6 - 2 = 4$.
I'm not too sure whether the argument above using the canonical splitting is wrong, or my manual calculation is (which should be a repetition of what I outlined above for $\mathbb{CP}^1$). I also see some references stating that the curvature of the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is $\frac{i}{(1+z\bar{z})^{2}} dz \wedge d\bar{z}$, which differs by a factor of 2 to what I've written above, resulting in the first Chern number not agreeing with the Euler characteristic. I would love to know where these discrepancies are coming from, and whether I am mixing up concepts - please feel free to correct me if I made any misleading statements!

You made a mistake in the first calculation (which however doesn't change the result): $c(T\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^n) = (1 + x)^{n + 1}$, not $(1 + x)^n$, so both $c_1(T\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2)$ and $c_1(T\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^1)$ are off by $x$ and the errors cancel out. With this change, the first calculation looks correct to me and agrees with Ted Shifrin's answer to the question you linked, so the error is likely to be in the second calculation.

The end of the second paragraph asserts that the tangent bundle of the projective line and normal bundle of the projective line in the projective plane have the same first Chern class. I haven't checked carefully, but if that isn't affected by Ben's comment, then the first calculation is also wrong: The tangent bundle is $\mathcal{O}(2)$ while the normal bundle is $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

@AndrewD.Hwang My comment implies that $c_1(T\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^1) = 2x$ while $c_1(N\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^1) = x$, so this works out.

@BenSteffan That does work out and makes a lot of sense - thanks!
